# Wildfly 13 - Proper project setup using logback in an ear project

Tags: wildfly, logback, logback-classic, wildfly-13

I am deploying my application as an ear archive in wildfly 13. The ear contains a war and an ejb. The ejb is used in different projects. I want to log the information from the war and the ejb into a single file to have the full context what happend in a single logfile.

I managed to log from the war via logback, but the logs from the ejb are not logged via logback.

My current setup:

- In my ear-module I have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my ear file to exclude the logging subsystem
- In my web-module the logback.xml is located in WEB-INF/classes
- In my web-module I have the dependencies to logback-classic and slf4j
- In my ejb-module I have a dependency to slf4j

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just logging to a file you could use a [logging-profile](http://docs.wildfly.org/15/Admin_Guide.html#logging-profiles) which would allow you to make runtime changes and not have to redploy your application if you want to make changes to your logging configuration.

### Using WildFly Logging

**Example Profile Configuration**

```
/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=ear1:add
/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=ear1/pattern-formatter=PATTERN:add(pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n")
/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=ear1/periodic-rotating-file-handler=FILE:add(append=true, suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd", named-formatter=PATTERN, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path="ear1.log"})
/subsystem=logging/logging-profile=ear1/root-logger=ROOT:add(level=INFO, handlers=[FILE])
```

Then you'd just add `Logging-Profile: ear1` entry in your EAR's manifest.

### Using Logback

If you want to continue using logback you'd need to put the logback and slf4j dependencies in your `EAR/lib` directory. The trick will be figuring out where to put the logback configuration file. It might work in `EAR/META-INF` or in the `EAR/lib`, but I'm not certain. It may even work if you kept it in the `WAR/WEB-INF/classes`, but you'd need to ensure a logger is accessed in the WAR before one is accessed in the EJB.

You'll also want to ensure you exclude the `org.slf4j.api` module or the `logging` subsystem for the EAR and each subdeloyment in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`.